# Error in CTE when using row_number() in mysql. I don't know why the error is showing up

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, common-table-expression, mysql-error-1064, row-number

```
WITH
team as (
        select 
        row_number() over() as id,
        team_code,
        team_name
        from teams
)
```

I got this error :- [12:06:32   WITH team as (             select              row_number() over() as id,             team_code,             team_name             from teams ) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8    0.000 sec]

I have no clue why was there an error.

Comment: OK xxou have an error and you didn't show us the actual query , if that is the quer you must check the manual `with cte as (select..) select a from cte`

Comment: `Row_number` without `order by` is not deterministic, but should work. And works as you can see in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nxi1IZQo). There must be something other in your code, which you did not show.

Comment: Ponder Stibbons didnt emphasize the important part enough: *There must be something other in your code, which you did not show.* If this is your whole code (and your error message suggests it is), it is not complete and you have to add something after that code, e.g. something like `select * from team` as in the fiddle he added.

Comment: I was creating a CTE and the error was on this code only.

Comment: I got it guys I was not using a select statement to use the CTE that's why it showed an error

Comment: @KartikeRaj if you dont mind can you please paste the syntax you have followed for above query in MYSQL , I am facing same issue